# Set on demand foreign key in DataBase

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have table in my data base with these specs:

- one PK
- 3 fields with foreign key
- some statistic fields

problem is here:

In every row only one FK field will be filled.
What is the best solution A or B?

A- define 3 FK for my table

B- define one field as FK_TYPE and one field as DEMAND_FK and use checking on FK_TYPE for result

Comment: because of my low reputation I cant share schema of these tables!

Comment: "I cant share schema of these tables" - you can if you script them out and you edit them into your question as code. I suspect what you tried to do is give us an image - which is *less* useful than having the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A - if you've got to have this design, you'll need a separate column for each foreign key. There's no (standard) way to define a "conditional" foreign key.

If your system supports check constraints, include a check constraint so that exactly one of the FK columns is not null. If it doesn't support check constraints, add triggers that enforce this same check.

Comment: thanks for this key word! "Conditional foreign key". This was what I need for Googling my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, B can not be possible in any relational database. Foreign key can only reference to only one primary key of a table. If you use B then you have to add the constrain in application level. Otherwise use A.